# i want to take raw_input and see if any of it is in a list, and if so, print the whole raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of breakfast choices. Then, I ask the user what they like for breakfast. If anything they type is in the list, then I want to print out the user's answer. How do I do this?

```
def bfast_choices():
    choices = ['eggs', 'bacon', 'toast', 'pancakes']
    choice = raw_input('> ')
    if choice in choices:
        print "%s is a great breakfast" % choice
    else:
        print "%s is gross" % choice
```

This works if the user only inputs 'eggs' or 'bacon' or 'toast' or 'pancakes'. However, I'd like it to work if they input 'eggs and bacon' or 'steak and eggs' or 'pancakes and waffles and coffee'  etc... Is this possible for python to check and see if at least one of the words in the list is in the input then print the whole input if it is?

Comment: Sure. Add `'a, b, z, and q'` to your list. Is this your actual question, or only sample code?

Comment: What if someone entered "bacon and pretzels". Seeing that pretzels is not in the list, what is the expected output for that?

Comment: for my purposes i would want it to print out "bacon and pretzels is a great breakfast"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming if the user inputs the string 'a, b, z, and q' you want your variable 'choice', to be a list of [a,b,z,q]. To do this, look into the string.split() and string.strip() commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *"if item in list"*

```
foodItem= raw_input("Enter choice:  ")

menu=["food1", "food2",  "food3"] 

if foodItem in menu:
  print(foodItem)
```

For list of foods:

```
foodItems= ["food1",  "food2"]

menu=["food1", "food4",  "food3"] 

for item in foodItems:
 if item in menu:
  print(item+"is available")
```

The remaining question is, getting user inputs into a list, you can do it in so many ways.
The usual and easy way is this:

```
foodItem= raw_input("Enter food(separated by ","):  )
foodItems=[i for i in foodItem.split(", ")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you can try this:

```
def bfast_choices():
    choices = ['eggs', 'bacon', 'toast', 'pancakes']
    choice = raw_input('> ')
    tmp = choice.split(' ')
    for item in tmp:
        if item in choices:
            print "%s is a great breakfast" % choice
            return

    print "%s is gross" % choice


bfast_choices()
```

You use the method `split(' ')`. It returns a list of words in the input. If the input is `eggs and pizza`, the list will be `['eggs', 'and', 'pizza']`. And then you iterate through the list and if at least one of the items from the list is in the list `choices` it prints that it is a great breakfast. This is just to give you an idea. You can modify it further to cover other possible scenarios.